# ASP.NET web api not responding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

There api:
http://api.yandexzaim.ru/api/soft_uslugi2

If I speak in visual studio project to the api via:

```
function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("/api/soft_uslugi2",
            function (data) {
                $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.

                // Loop through the list of products.
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    // Add a table row for the product.
                    var row = '<td>' + val.uname + '</td><td>' + val.id + '</td>';
                    $('<tr/>', { text: row })  // Append the name.
                        .appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(getProducts);
```

That's OK, but if I turn to the same server api

```
function getProducts() {
        $.getJSON("http://api.yandexzaim.ru/api/soft_uslugi2",
            function (data) {
                $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.

                // Loop through the list of products.
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    // Add a table row for the product.
                    var row = '<td>' + val.uname + '</td><td>' + val.id + '</td>';
                    $('<tr/>', { text: row })  // Append the name.
                        .appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(getProducts);
```

Let nothing back ... What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're encountering the Same-Origin Policy?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy  Are you able to invoke the API manually with a browser client?

Comment: yes, from browser  answer is.